# reactjs props getting lost in Route creation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-props

I'm attempting to pass a user's auth state down to components via a `react-router-dom` switch block (I believe I *ought* to look at implementing `redux` but that's a question for later).

There's a `Home` view that gets passed all the login information after the user authenticates, and I can see the `authState` object as a prop in the home component using react devtools:

```
import React from "react";
import Dashboard from "../Dashboard";
import {Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import NoMatch from "../NoMatch";

function Home(props) {
// authState exists
    return (
        <Switch {...props}>
            // authState exists
            <Route exact path="/" render={(...props) => <Dashboard {...props} />} /> // authState gone
            <Route component={NoMatch} />
        </Switch>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

after executing this it renders the `Dashboard`, and tracing down the component chain with react devtools I can see that the prop has been passed from the `Home` component to the `Switch` component successfully. However, once it gets to the `Route` the prop is gone, and the only props available in the `Dashboard` component are the `history`, `location` and `match` props.

Why are the props missing and what's the right way to pass them down?

Comment: You have `props` within the scope of `Home` and within the render function of `Route`. The higher scoped variable will be shadowed by the lower. You can rename one and spread both: `(renderProps) => <Dashbaord {...props} {...renderProps} />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of improvements needed in your code:

- Passing props to `Switch` component is unnecessary
- No need to collect router props using the rest syntax only to spread them later

**Main Problem:**

- `props` inside the function passed to `render` prop refers to the router props instead of the props passed to `Home` component. You are using the same identifier for two different things.

**Solution**

Use different names for router props and the props passed to `Home` component that you want to pass down to `Dashboard` component

```
function Home(props) {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route
         exact
         path="/"
         render={(routerProps) => <Dashboard {...routerProps} {...props} />}
      />
      <Route component={NoMatch} />
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't need access to router props in the `Dashboard` component, remove the `props` parameter from the `render` prop function.

```
<Route
   exact
   path="/"
   render={() => <Dashboard {...props} />}
/>
```

Now, you won't have access to router props inside the `Dashboard` component but the auth state of the user will be passed down to `Dashboard` component.

Answer (score 0):

In the most recent versions of the `react-router-dom` you must replace `render` and `component` attributes with `element`. You cannot pass a callback function there in which there were specified the route props anymore.

Instead you can use a hook in your routed component:

```
const params = useParams();
```

to obtain the parameters.

See more in the [official documentation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/faq).